# Using arrays to add large numbers

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I need to add two numbers of length 50 using arrays. I believe I have done the correct conversions, but I don't exactly know how to return the final sum to be printed. Is my method used for addition correct? Do I need a return type or can I use it to return nothing (*void*)?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class intAdding {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x,y;
    String a[] = new String[50];
    String b[] = new String[50];

    System.out.println("Please enter two numbers with up to 50 digits: ");
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    x = stdIn.next();
    y = stdIn.next();

    System.out.println("first number: " + x);
    System.out.println("second number: " + y);

    a[] = stringToIntArray(x);
    a[] = stringToIntArray(y);
    int[] result = new int[51];
    result = null;

    addnum(a, b, result);
    System.out.println(result);

  }
  void addnum(int c[50], int d[50], int sum[51]) {
      int carry=0;
      int temp;
      int i;

      for(i=0; i<=50; i++) {
         temp=c[i]+d[i]+carry;
         sum[i]=temp%10;
         carry=temp/10;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `a[] = stringToIntArray(y);` should probably be `b[] = stringToIntArray(y);`.  You are currently overwriting a[].

Comment: Why don't you want to use BigInteger API?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: im tempted to use BigInteger (I've had this suggested and have seen it doing the research to find potential answeres on my own), but I believe the point of this assignment is to understand the difference behind the scenes as programs are built.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do it is using `BigInteger`. The array logic is all handled under the hood:

```
BigInteger bigX = new BigInteger(x);
BigInteger bigY = new BigInteger(y);

BigInteger sum = bigX.add(bigY);
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: I might just end up using this if i cant get it to compile correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since array are reference type, you don't have to return explicitly the result. The `void` is OK with addNum() method. You have to make the following changes (remove null assignment with result)-

```
int[] result = new int[51];
addnum(a, b, result);
System.out.println(result);
```

More over you have to make to following change -

```
b[] = stringToIntArray(y); //instead of a[] = stringToIntArray(y);
```

But best way to use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Yes I might use the BigInteger method but I am trying to figure it out the long way first. I believe this has helped, thank you

Comment: I think it would be way more reasonable to return array as only method itself knows how long result should be... and in general  "add" on numeric type should return result so it can be chained into normal expression like `addnum(addnum(a,b),c)`...